# Python Documentation on Classes - Incorrect reference to C++

Tags: python, c++, oop

**Python** documentation on Classes refers to **C++** class members are normally `public`.

> In C++ terminology, normally class members (including the data
> members) are public (except see below Private Variables), and all
> member functions are virtual.

[Python Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Am I missing something in here, since the default access of the members within a **C++** class are `private`?

Comment: The above talks about how Python classes work, not C++ -- as if in C++ all class members are public and methods are virtual. That's how Python works.

Comment: Agree with @Sam, it's saying all members of a Python class are like C++ class members that have been declared public.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are simply misreading the quote.

"*In C++ terminology,*" is supposed to mean that the quote explains (or approximates) Python's behavior using some terms with meaning specific to C++. It does not mean that the sentence is explaining C++ behavior.

"*normally class members*" is referring to members of a Python `class`, not a C++ class or the C++ keyword `class`.

"*are public*" is where the C++ terminology comes in. There is no (real) `public`/`private` distinction in Python, so all members behave as if they were declared `public`, if the Python class was rewritten as a C++ class.

---

And for completeness: In C++ class members can be either `private` or `public` by default. This depends on whether the class is introduced with the `class`, the `struct` or the `union` keyword. Note that either keywords are used to introduce a class, so there is a difference between the C++ language construct of a *class* and the C++ keyword `class`.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about the context in which they've written that but I think they meant that without explicitly mentioning the public or private access modifiers, by default the variables and the functions in classes are set to be public members.
Python sets all its class variables and functions to be public and leaves the responsibility to the programmer without any access modifiers.

Comment: I know, I meant that in python variables and funxtion are always set to be public.

Comment: "*without explicitly mentioning the public or private access modifiers*" makes it sound as if these modifiers could be mentioned.

Comment: Technically, python allows the user an option of readonly without changing the actual value of the given variable. It isn't private but it does allow a certain access constrains.